# Pyspark script to copy table data from postgres to s3 in parquet format

Tags: python, postgresql, pyspark, databricks

I am working on a pyspark script to copy data from postgres table to s3 in parquet format.
My table has more than 150 million records. The script works fine if a limit the row count but cannot load the complete data.

Please give your suggestions to improve the performance.

'''

```
import psycopg2
import datetime
class DataMigrator:


  def __init__(self, database, schema, host, table, partition_key, s3bucket):
    self.database = database
    self.host = host
    self.schema = schema
    self.table = table
    self.bucket = s3bucket
    self.partition_key = partition_key
    
  def connection_props(self):
 
    jdbcHostname = self.host 
    jdbcDatabase = self.database
    jdbcPort = 5432
    username= 
    password= 
    jdbcUrl = {4}&ssl=false'".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase, username, password)
    connectionProperties = {
                            "user" : username,
                            "password" : password,
                            
                          }
    return connectionProperties, jdbcUrl
    
  
  def read_data(self):
    conpropererties = self.connection_props()[0]
    url = self.connection_props()[1]
    pushdown_query = "(select * from {DB}.{SCHEMA}.{TABLE} ) a".format(DB=self.database, SCHEMA=self.schema, TABLE=self.table)
    df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table=pushdown_query, properties=conpropererties).coalesce(200)
    return df 
 
  def write_parquet(self):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    dataframe = self.read_data()
    
    #print(ind, datetime.datetime.now())
    dataframe.write.partitionBy("{PARTITON_KEY}".format(PARTITON_KEY=self.partition_key))\
      .mode("overwrite")\
      .parquet("s3a://{BUCKET}/migration/{table}".format(BUCKET=self.bucket, TABLE=self.table))

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
  migrator = DataMigrator(database='coficoreply', schema='coficoreply', host=' ', table='item',  partition_key='created', s3bucket='db2-databricks-prod/dwh')
  migrator.write_parquet()
```

'''

Comment: Why are you doing coalesce(200)?

Comment: Why don't you batch it?